# Swiftでニ次元配列から先頭の値の配列を取得したい

Tags: swift

以下のような二次元配列があった場合に

```
var arrayTest = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

[1,1,1]のように先頭の値を取り出して配列を作りたい場合、Swiftでどのように書けば良いですか？
for文を使わずに取り出すことが出来ますか？

[2,2,2]なども取り出せるような方法で教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swift > Array > map(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map)

mapメソッドを使うと処理が容易です。

```
let newArray = arrayTest.map {
    $0[0]
}
// [1, 1, 1]
```

ほかにも関数型言語から流用してきたメソッドがいくつもあるので、Xcodeのリファレンスでざっと見渡してみるといいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます!!できました